# Datepart result format as time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    d.Nip,d.FullName,b.*,c.InTime,c.OutTime, 
    (SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, OutTime)) - (SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, InTime)) as lebih 
FROM 
    DinasAuditHeader a 
INNER JOIN
    DinasAuditDetail b on a.KodeAuditHeader = b.KodeAuditHeader 
INNER JOIN
    Attendance c on b.Nip = c.Nip and b.attendancedate = c.AttendanceDate 
INNER JOIN
    employee d on c.Nip = d.Nip 
WHERE
    b.Nip = '1502427' 
    AND c.AttendanceCode = 'P3' 
    AND a.KodeAuditHeader = 'AD0000001'
```

From the query I get this result

```
Nip      FullName   KodeDetailDinas KodeAuditHeader nip    AttendanceDate   claim_status    InTime                      OutTime         lebih
1502427 FERNANDO ALIM      1          AD0000001   1502427   2016-08-28           0      2016-08-28 08:55:00.000 2016-08-28 21:03:00.000 13
1502427 FERNANDO ALIM      3          AD0000001   1502427   2016-08-30           0      2016-08-30 08:55:00.000 2016-08-30 18:03:00.000 10
1502427 FERNANDO ALIM      2          AD0000001   1502427   2016-08-29           0      2016-08-29 08:55:00.000 2016-08-29 19:03:00.000 11
1502427 FERNANDO ALIM      4          AD0000001   1502427   2016-08-31           0      2016-08-31 08:50:00.000 2016-08-31 20:03:00.000 12
```

As you can see from my query and the result. I have a column called with `lebih`. `lebih` is a result range between `InTime` and `OutTime`.

I have two question(s).

1. From my query above i only can get `hour`. So how to convert it with this format `hh:mm`
2. How to see the range between them (`OutTime` - `InTime`) and then subtract with `- 08:00` ?

Comment: what is meant by range in betwen in time and outime ?can you share some info on how the value is calculated

Comment: 2016-08-28 21:03:00.000 -  2016-08-28 08:55:00.000 But only the `datetime part`

Comment: i didn;t get it,which datetime part,is it minutes, ..?

Comment: I can't write and speak english well, sorry . Coloumn `OutTime` and `InTime`

Comment: You could try the query I have posted below

Comment: @ReyanChougle yeah it's work. But can i substract it with `- 8 Hours`

Comment: @YVS1102 can you give an example so that I can help you on that. As the query mentioned by you subtracts OutTime and InTime.

Comment: You can do any kind of modifications in the query to get the desired results

Comment: @ReyanChougle with your query i get this `09:08` in `lebih`. Can i substract it (lebih coloumn) with 8 hour. So i can get this `01:08`

Comment: @YVS1102 I have updated my post to subtract 8 hours from lebih. If it works then you can accept my post as your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),(OutTime - InTime),108) AS lebih`

Below Sql query should work in your case:

```
SELECT 
    d.Nip,d.FullName,b.*,c.InTime,c.OutTime, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),(OutTime - InTime),108) AS lebih
FROM 
    DinasAuditHeader a 
INNER JOIN
    DinasAuditDetail b on a.KodeAuditHeader = b.KodeAuditHeader 
INNER JOIN
    Attendance c on b.Nip = c.Nip and b.attendancedate = c.AttendanceDate 
INNER JOIN
    employee d on c.Nip = d.Nip 
WHERE
    b.Nip = '1502427' 
    AND c.AttendanceCode = 'P3' 
    AND a.KodeAuditHeader = 'AD0000001'
```

**UPDATE:**

To subtract 8 hours from lebih, you can use

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(HOUR, -8, OutTime - InTime), 108) AS lebih
```

Answer (score 1):

For question number 1. U can use @Unnikrishnan R answer. Then For number two try the query below.

```
SELECT 
    d.Nip,d.FullName,b.*,c.InTime,c.OutTime, LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,InTime,OutTime),'2011-01-01 00:00') AS TIME),5) lebih ,
    LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,InTime,DATEADD(HOUR, -8, OutTime)),'2011-01-01 00:00') AS TIME),5) 
FROM DinasAuditHeader a 
 INNER JOIN DinasAuditDetail b on a.KodeAuditHeader = b.KodeAuditHeader 
 INNER JOIN Attendance c on b.Nip = c.Nip and b.attendancedate = c.AttendanceDate 
 INNER JOIN employee d on c.Nip = d.Nip 
WHERE b.Nip = '1502427' and c.AttendanceCode = 'P3' and a.KodeAuditHeader = 'AD0000001'
order by KodeDetailDinas asc
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple cast to `VARCHAR` appended by `':00'`?

```
SELECT 
    d.Nip,d.FullName,b.*,c.InTime,c.OutTime, 
    cast((SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, OutTime)) - (SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, InTime)) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':00' as lebih 
    FROM DinasAuditHeader a 
    inner join DinasAuditDetail b on a.KodeAuditHeader = b.KodeAuditHeader 
    inner join Attendance c on b.Nip = c.Nip and b.attendancedate = c.AttendanceDate 
    inner join employee d on c.Nip = d.Nip 
where b.Nip = '1502427' and c.AttendanceCode = 'P3' and a.KodeAuditHeader = 'AD0000001'
```

If you want to make it precise to `MINUTE`, better use `DATEDIFF`

```
select 
    d.Nip,d.FullName,b.*,c.InTime,c.OutTime, 
    cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, InTime, OutTime) / 60) as varchar(2)) + ':' 
    + cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, InTime, OutTime) % 60) as varchar(2))
    FROM DinasAuditHeader a 
    inner join DinasAuditDetail b on a.KodeAuditHeader = b.KodeAuditHeader 
    inner join Attendance c on b.Nip = c.Nip and b.attendancedate = c.AttendanceDate 
    inner join employee d on c.Nip = d.Nip 
where b.Nip = '1502427' and c.AttendanceCode = 'P3' and a.KodeAuditHeader = 'AD0000001'
```

If you want to further minute the time result by 8 hours, you can put the `OutTime` 8 hours backward first.

```
select 
    d.Nip,d.FullName,b.*,c.InTime,c.OutTime, 
    cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, InTime, DATEADD(HOUR, -8, OutTime)) / 60) as varchar(2)) + ':' 
    + cast(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, InTime, DATEADD(HOUR, -8, OutTime)) % 60) as varchar(2))
    FROM DinasAuditHeader a 
    inner join DinasAuditDetail b on a.KodeAuditHeader = b.KodeAuditHeader 
    inner join Attendance c on b.Nip = c.Nip and b.attendancedate = c.AttendanceDate 
    inner join employee d on c.Nip = d.Nip 
where b.Nip = '1502427' and c.AttendanceCode = 'P3' and a.KodeAuditHeader = 'AD0000001'
```

Comment: How can i do this `lebih coloum` - `08:00` ?

Comment: @YVS1102 sorry I don't quite get it. Do you mean to reverse the time by 8 hours?

Comment: I meann substract it with 8 hour

Answer (score 0):

Use the script to get the time difference in 'HH:MM'.

```
SELECT 
    d.Nip,d.FullName,b.*,c.InTime,c.OutTime, 
    LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,InTime,OutTime),'2011-01-01 00:00') AS TIME),5) as lebih
FROM DinasAuditHeader a 
 INNER JOIN DinasAuditDetail b on a.KodeAuditHeader = b.KodeAuditHeader 
 INNER JOIN Attendance c on b.Nip = c.Nip and b.attendancedate = c.AttendanceDate 
 INNER JOIN employee d on c.Nip = d.Nip 
WHERE b.Nip = '1502427' and c.AttendanceCode = 'P3' and a.KodeAuditHeader = 'AD0000001'
```

See the result of a sample query.
[Time difference in HH:MM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lNOS.png)

Comment: can you explain what is this `2011-01-01 00:00` ?

Comment: and can i do a math inside the query ? example the value of `lebih - 08:00 hour`

Comment: that is simply a trick to convert the result to expected time format.. just adding a date(any date) with time and second field as 00:00 against the result of the datediff function.we can't explicitly convert the minute difference to the time datatype.